# Why should I specify a 'pulse width' when firing a thyristor rectifier/inverter?

Tags: power-electronics, bridge-rectifier, simulink, thyristor

If I'm correct, the controller will send a gate signal to this bridge (6-pulse or 12-pulse) and even if it sends them with 1 degree of width, the thyristors must close until the current through it crosses zero right? 
As reference I was reviewing **power_hvdc** and **power_hvdc12pulse** examples included in Matlab / Simulink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pulse width refers to the duration of the gate firing pulse. The firing angle is determined by the delay time between the zero crossing point and initiation of the gate pulse. The thyristor does not turn on instantaneously, it requires some time, perhaps 1 to 50 microseconds. The minimum required pulse width would be determined from the thyristor specification. The minimum required gate pulse time may vary with the current that the gate drive circuit supplies.

Comment: http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics_technical/application_notes/switching_thyristor/littelfuse_triggering_and_gate_characteristics_of_thyristors_application_note.pdf p23ff

Comment: @Janka Thank you. That reference is surprisingly similar to my General Electric SCR Manual Fifth Edition 1972.

Answer (score 1):

> Why should I specify a 'pulse width' when firing a thyristor rectifier/inverter?

The pulse width is related to the firing angle \$\alpha\$ from the commutation point.

> the thyristors must close until the current through it crosses zero right?

You may not be able to close the thyristor directly, but you are definitely in control of when to fire the thyristors and can close them indirectly. When one thyristor fires, the one that was previously conducting will stop conducting because its voltage is less than the one that just fired. Thus it closes.

[image]
[Source](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/news/summer2002/converter6.shtm)